# why is my wildcard character not registering through the directory?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subfolder looping script that identifies if `Cells(2,3)` is blank, and then proceeds to delete the column, if so.

I have a wildcard character `*` in order to not have to name any of the files, just extensions. Why is this line: `MyFile = "*.xlsx"` not picking up the actual file names? It's just displaying as `*.xlsx` within the loop and exiting the sub because nothing is found.

Edited Code based on Answer:

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()

    Dim folder As Object
    Dim subfolders As Object
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim currentfile As Object, currentfolder As Object

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    Set subfolders = folder.subfolders
    MyFile = "*.xlsx"

    For Each subfolders In subfolders

    Set CurrentFile = subfolders.Files

    With New FileSystemObject ' reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime library

        Dim root As folder
        Set root = .GetFolder("C:\Users\pp87255\Desktop\JNav Rest\05.23.2019")

        Dim subFolder As folder
        For Each subFolder In root.subfolders

            Dim currentfolder As folder
            For Each currentfolder In subFolder.subfolders

                Dim currentfile As File
                For Each currentfile In currentfolder.Files
                    If currentfile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
                        Dim wb As Workbook
                        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(currentfile.Path)
                        If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value2 = "" Then
                            Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With


    Next

    Set folder = Nothing
    Set subfolders = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Because Excel doesn't expand wildcards. Wildcard support is part of the command processor, not Excel.

Comment: @KenWhite how am I supposed to reference each file without explicitly naming each one? I just want it to apply this to all files with a specific extension

Comment: Then you need to extract the extension from `CurrFile.Name` and compare it directly to another extension. You can't use a wildcard to do so.

Comment: Loop through all the files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then
> ```

With `MyFile` being `"*.xlsx"`, the `=` comparison operator is correctly saying "nope, doesn't match".

What you want is to replace that operator with the `Like` operator, with the caveat that you'll need a literal expression on the right-hand side:

```
If CurrFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
```

That should work as intended... until this part:

> ```
> Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & MyFile)
> ```

You probably mean to use `CurrFile` there (`Workbooks.Open` isn't expecting a wildcard in the filename there)... but this is weird and ambiguous:

> ```
> For Each CurrFile In CurrFile
> ```

Don't do that. Declare a new variable instead or repurposing an existing one in the same scope. Same here:

> ```
> For Each subfolders In subfolders
> ```

You want `For Each subFolder In subFolders`, then `For Each currFile In currFiles`, maybe - or better:

```
With New FileSystemObject ' reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime library

    Dim root As Folder
    Set root = .GetFolder("C:\Users\pp87255\Desktop\JNav Rest\05.23.2019")

    Dim subFolder As Folder
    For Each subFolder In root.SubFolders

        Dim currentFolder As Folder
        For Each currentFolder In subFolder.SubFolders

            Dim currentFile As File
            For Each currentFile In currentFolder.Files
                If currentFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
                    Dim wb As Workbook
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(currentFile.Path)
                    '...
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Working late-bound is hard if you're not familiar with the libraries involved. The good news is, there's no reason whatsoever to late-bind the `Scripting` library (it's the same version on every Windows box ever built this century) - so go to Tools > Rerefences, and check the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library.

Comment: are you suggesting I add two new object variables: `subfolder` and `currFiles`?

Comment: And could I just edit the above line to: `Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path "\"& "*.xlsx"`  or would that not work with the wildcard character, either?

Comment: @nicklanta yes. and you don't need `fso`, that one can just be `With CreateObject(...)`.....`End With`.

Comment: getting an object not support by this property/method, with this line: `Set CurrFile = subfolders.Files`

Comment: I apologize, I'm not very familiar with the object-oriented side of VBA, so all of this is pretty new to me. Is there anyway you could copy the code I posted and make the tiny edits so I can see how this all comes together? It would make better sense that way, if possible

Comment: @nicklanta edited, hope it helps; note that `As Object` is making things much harder than they need to be.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still lost. This stuffs a bit over my head, currently. I don't know what to take out and bring in with this new info

Comment: It's prompting an object required error on this `For Each currentFolder in folder.subfolders` which looks like it will trigger same error on the `currnent files` for loop

Comment: Looks like you made a typo somewhere. Make sure `Option Explicit` is specified at the top of the module. Did you declare `currentFolder`?

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your edit, where am I replacing that code in my og post? As in if I just made a new module, pasted the code you created, what else am I appending to it in order to work for me?

Comment: Stop. You're not **pasting** anything. You're trying to *understand* what you're looking at. **Type** it.

Comment: I am reading through it, but what else from my other code am I keeping? Everything? am I replacing your code in place of a block of code from my og post?

Comment: `With New FileSystemObject` replaces `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` - at `End With`, the next line would be `With Application`. The inner part (where you conditionally delete rows) is omitted, you'll want to have it there, after `Set wb = ...`.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused if I need to edit further, but I edited my original post to reflect the changes. am I at least close?

Answer (score 0):

I repurposed this code from "www.thespreadsheetguru.com".  It loops through all files in the folder I navigate to, and formats them.

```
Private Sub FormatAllFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim myFileName As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim regionNumber As String

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "SELECT THE FOLDER WITH REPORT COLLECTION WORKBOOKS TO BE FORMATTED"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = ".xlsx"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  MyFile = Dir(myPath)
  'branchLocation = fso.GetBaseName(Right(myFile, Len(myFile) - InStr(myFile, "_")))

  GetSaveFileLocation

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While MyFile <> ""

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    myFileName = fso.GetBaseName(MyFile)

    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & MyFile)

      fName = myFileName & "_Formatted"
      saveFileName = mySavePath & fName & myExtension

      If WB.Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
        WB.Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
      End If

      ExecutiveReportFormatting

      regionNumber = getRegionNumber(myFileName)

      WB.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments").Value = regionNumber

    'Close Workbook
    With WB
        .SaveAs saveFileName
        .Close
    End With

    'Get next file name
      MyFile = Dir

  Loop

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

Comment: The `GetSaveFileLocation` sub isn't in that code, was that included?

Comment: @nicklanta if it isn't, its mechanics can trivially be inferred from the `FldrPicker` code that's right there.